# Unable to retrieve data from sql server database using nhibernate in asp.net mvc 3 framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

```
   using (ISession session = NHibernateSession.OpenSession())
        {
             var employees = session.Query<Employee>().ToList();
             return View(employees);
        }
```

I am not able to get data from db i have created mapping file in hbm folder. I have created session and I am alse not able to save data in table getting "no persister error".

Answer (score 0):

please try one of the following:

1. Did you set your .hbm file to EmbeddedResource (hbm file, Properties - Build Action, set Embedded Resource)?
2. Did you [add your mappings](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-programmatic) to your NHibernate.Configuration (e.g. new Configuration().AddAssembly( typeof(Employee).Assembly))?

Comment: After setting employee.hbm.xml file to embedded resource I can getting this error .Possible cause: no assembly name specified

Comment: Could not compile the mapping document: PractProj.MappingFile.hbm.Employee.hbm.xml getting this exception after adding employee.hbm.xml to embedded resource

Comment: Could not load type 'PractProj.MappingFile.Employee' from assembly 'PractProj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: Tag "hibernate-mapping" in your mapping files is probably missing attribute assembly. The "assembly" and "namespace" are recommended for tag "hibernate-mapping". You can omit them, but in such you have to specify fully qualified name, 
e.g. 

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class name="Employee"> 

instead of 

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Employee" namespace="PractProj.MappingFile">
<class name="Employee">. 

See attributes of [hibernate-mapping](www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-mapping).